# MacOS - This disk doesn't use the GUID partition table scheme error

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra, macos-mojave

When I try to reinstall MacOS (or to restore a timeMachine backup), on a new (SSD )Hard drive, I get the above error.
What should you do?

Comment: Launch Disk Utility, Erase the volume and select GUID scheme.

Comment: Not a programming question - try https://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 4):

Enter disk utility. 
Erasing the hard drive (Macintosh HD) won't work, it is only an image of the hard drive and now the hardware itself. 
You need to erase and change the formatting of the physical device (hard drive) to GUID.
TO do so click on `View` and select `Show All Devices`
Then erase and reformat the actual hard drive.

Your hardware is now GUID and you can proceed with your install